# CSS grid framework percentage

Tags: css

I am implementing a CSS grid as a learning experience and based on my study and reading of the following:

http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

Percentage based grids make the most sense, however when handling thirds, how does that work, if fractions are to add up to 100%?

33% + 33% + 33% is obviously 99% -- what effect (if any) does this have on using thirdds in CSS frameworks for grid layout???

Lastly, why does so many frameworks tend to focus on so many column units? YUI Pure for instance supports 24 units which makes the CSS harder to understand at first glance and for what, to provide more "pixel perfect precision"?

To me it seems logical to support 4 or 5 columns at most, and embed grids inside of grids for more fine grained layout control.

Using a grid removes pixel precision any way doesn't it? Every web site these days is segmented into 4 or five columns anyhow.

Opinions, experiences, suggestions????

Comment: If you review the article, 'thirds' are defined as 33.33% which is a pretty close to 100% (99.99%) when multiplied and Chris' point was that's close enough. If you want pixel perfect accuracy...don't use it that way.

Comment: Ya good point...I may be over thinking...or under thinking...if you had only 4 columns for example, and had to embed grids inside grids, it would save on CSS maybe but require more markup, I think...it's interesting but this level of CSS is very new to me :)

Comment: 24 can be easily divisible by a number of factors, giving more variance.

Answer (score 3):

A few answers to the multiple (good!) questions you pose:

- Percentages do not need to be integers. So doing `width: 33.3333%` can get you very close to 100%. Not adding up to 100 will leave you a tiny bit short of full width, but if you are close enough, nobody will notice.
- Why so many columns? Because content varies in size, and the more columns you have, the more adaptable your gird is. Here's an excellent presentation on grids entitled "Grids Are Good (Right?)" that, while a few years old, is still worth a look at. Here it is in [a PDF](http://www.subtraction.com/pics/0703/grids_are_good.pdf) or [on slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/huer1278ft/grids-are-good-right)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the columns, it gives you more control over posititioning elements. I typically use a `16` grid system (4,4,4,4) for my desktop layouts, but if you wanted to position it from say `col_3` to `col_6`, it allows for that.

I've provided a picture for a visual aid.

[image: 24 grid system]